# A combinatorics question - sequence with zeroes and ones

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving this problem, and I encountered the difficulty of having to find the solution of finding all $11$-term sequences.

A sequence of $1$'s ans $0$'s cannot have three zeroes in a row. How many $11$-term sequences are possible?

Comment: Notice that any such sequence must begin with $1$, $01$, or $001$.  Can you write a recurrence relation?

Comment: Thanks! I've got an idea now!

Comment: What is a $11$-term sequence?

Comment: +1 for Wolfgang comment. In this context it is not clear clear if "11-term" means binary "one one term" (such as some type of sequence with ones followed by ones in some way?) or "eleven term" (meaning a sequence of eleven bits?)  Likely the latter, but it took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a recurrence. You can build a sequence without 000 by adding 1 or 10 or 100 at the end of anything that works. This gives the following recurrence for the number $s_n$ of sequences you want:

$\begin{align*}
   s_{n + 3}
     &= s_{n + 2} + s_{n + 1} + s_n
\end{align*}$

As starting points you have $s_0 = 1$ (just the empty sequence), $s_1 = 2$ (sequences 1 and 0), $s_2 = 4$ (00, 01, 10, 11). Using the recurrence you can compute the required $s_{11} = 927$

(The recurrence is the one for the [Tribonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers), specifically $s_n = T_{n + 3}$. The reference gives closed formulas, but they are quite messy. Better write a one-off script to compute the needed value if small.)